# click numbers to show the next sequence of pagination using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

In Pagination I have ellipsis it should expand & display the next number in the sequence on clicking on the next & previous icon. Below is what I have tried. I don't want to use any plugin. Want to achieve this with pure jquery or javascript. Is it possible to achieve this with jquery or Javascript? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Below is my code & also a screenshot. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   

                let pageSize = 2;
              let pageCount = Math.ceil($('.content').length / 2);

              let showPage = function(page) {
                let start = pageSize * (page - 1);
                let end = pageSize * page;
                $(".content").hide().slice(start, end).show();
                
                $('#prev a').toggleClass('disabled', page <= 1);
                $('#next a').toggleClass('disabled', page >= pageCount);
              }

              showPage(1);

              $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
                $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
                showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
              });
                          
            });
```

```css
.content {
    margin: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

#pagin {
    clear: both;
    padding:0;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#pagin li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#pagin li a {
    display:block;
    color:#717171;
    font:bold 11px;
    text-shadow:0px 1px white;
    padding:5px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    background:#f9f9f9;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9',endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 );
}
#pagin li a.current {
    color:white;
    text-shadow:0px 1px #3f789f;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    background:#7cb9e5;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#7cb9e5 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#7cb9e5 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#7cb9e5 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#7cb9e5 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#7cb9e5 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7cb9e5',endColorstr='#57a1d8',GradientType=0 );
}
#pagin li a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#pagin li a:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    background:#fff;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#e8e8e8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff',endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 );
}
#pagin li a:active,#pagin li a.current:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
}
#pagin li a.current:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    background:#99cefc;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#99cefc 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#99cefc 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#99cefc 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#99cefc 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#99cefc 0%,#57a1d8 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99cefc',endColorstr='#57a1d8',GradientType=0 );
}
li{list-style-type:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-container" data-page="1">
  <div class="content">1 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">2 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">3 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">4 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">5 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">6 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">7 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">8 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">9 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">10 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">11 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">12 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">13 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">14 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">15 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">16 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">17 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">18 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">19 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">20 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">21 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">22 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">23 I have some content</div>
  <div class="content">24 I have some content</div>
</div>
<div  id="pagin">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="prev">
      <svg width="8" height="12" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7.15493e-08 6L6 12L7.41 10.59L2.83 6L7.41 1.41L6 7.15493e-08L7.15493e-08 6Z" fill="#212934"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a class="page current" href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">3</a></li>  
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">4</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">5</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">6</a></li>
  <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">7</a></li>
   <li class=""><a class="page" href="#">8</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="next">
      <svg width="7" height="11" viewBox="0 0 7 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.1748 5.75421L1.1748 0.754211L-0.000195489 1.92921L3.81647 5.75421L-0.000195398 9.57921L1.1748 10.7542L6.1748 5.75421Z" fill="#212934"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here's pagination without any plugin.
in this `($('.pagination'), 25, 5)` pass first argument your pagination wrapper class, second argument total number of pages, third is number of pages you want to show at a time.

```js
(function(baseElement, pages, pageShow){
  var pageNum = 0, pageOffset = 0;

  function _initNav(){
    //create pages
    for(i=1;i<pages+1;i++){
      $((i==1?'<li class="active">':'<li>')+(i)+'</li>').appendTo('.nav-pages', baseElement).css('min-width',pages.toString().length+'em');
    }
    
    //calculate initial values
    function ow(e){return e.first().outerWidth()}
    var w = ow($('.nav-pages li', baseElement)),bw = ow($('.nav-btn', baseElement));
    baseElement.css('width',w*pageShow+(bw*2)+'px');
    $('.nav-pages', baseElement).css('margin-left',bw+'px');
    
    //init events
    baseElement.on('click', '.nav-pages li, .nav-btn', function(e){
      if($(e.target).is('.nav-btn')){
        var toPage = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? pageNum-1 : pageNum+1;
      }else{
        var toPage = $(this).index(); 
      }
      _navPage(toPage);
    });
  }

  function _navPage(toPage){
    var sel = $('.nav-pages li', baseElement), w = sel.first().outerWidth(),
        diff = toPage-pageNum;
    
    if(toPage>=0 && toPage <= pages-1){
      sel.removeClass('active').eq(toPage).addClass('active');
      pageNum = toPage;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
    
    if(toPage<=(pages-(pageShow+(diff>0?0:1))) && toPage>=0){
      pageOffset = pageOffset + -w*diff;  
    }else{
      pageOffset = (toPage>0)?-w*(pages-pageShow):0;
    }
    
    sel.parent().css('left',pageOffset+'px');
  }
  
  _initNav();

})
($('.pagination'), 25, 5);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700");
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #efefef;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.pagination {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}
.pagination .nav-btn {
  font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00aaed, #3ac8ff);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 24px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.pagination .nav-btn:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #07baff, #3ac8ff);
  text-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.pagination .nav-btn.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.pagination .nav-btn.prev::before {
  content: "";
}
.pagination .nav-btn.next::before {
  content: "";
}
.pagination .nav-pages {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 300ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
}
.pagination .nav-pages li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination .nav-pages li.active, .pagination .nav-pages li:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="pagination">
  <div class="nav-btn prev"></div>
  <ul class="nav-pages"></ul>
  <div class="nav-btn next"></div>
</nav>
```

---

### Heading

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I also need the ellipsis in my requirement. it is nit working for me